# Reading the active slide # on angular ui boostrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [Angular Bootstrap carousel ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel) I need to use the carousel as an image selector, but I can't find a way to bind to the selected $index. Is there any way to do it, even a hacky way?

[Here's a plunkr to mess with](http://plnkr.co/edit/hOjax5mbXQncrO25iymh?p=preview).

I've tried putting an `ng-click=($index)` on the `<slide>` tag but that is under the slider controls, so it doesn't fire when the carousel is slid.

```
<carousel interval="carouselInterval" class="no-animate" >
    <slide ng-repeat="slide in token.images | eligibleWidth:200"
           class="no-animate" ng-click="slideSelect($index)"> <!-- doesn't fire cuz under controls -->
        <img ng-src="{{slide.src}}" style="margin:auto;">

        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>{{$index+1}} of {{(token.images | eligibleWidth:200).length}}</h4>

            <p >{{slide.caption}}</p>
        </div>
    </slide>
</carousel>
```

Comment: Can you post your demo code to jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure. http://plnkr.co/edit/hOjax5mbXQncrO25iymh?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a hacky way. Use onclick to trigger angular scope function.

```
<slide onclick="angular.element(this).scope().clickItem(this)" data-index="{{$index}}" >
   ...
<slide>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.clickItem = function(target){
    var ele = angular.element(target);
    var index = ele.attr('data-index');
};
```

Here is [PLUNKER DEMO LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/YJLlx9ZRiFeB4smIbOh4?p=preview)

Hope this can work.

Comment: Thanks - it may not have been clear in my question, but I needed the selectedIndex when the user uses the slide controls. See the comment in my markup "doesn't fire because under the controls". Your demo has the same problem. :(

Comment: Look into the bootstrap-ui source code. [They save the currentIndex as a private property in controller](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/carousel/carousel.js#L15). And I think this is not a good pratice. But after I check [this in slide directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/carousel/carousel.js#L277). Find out I can inspect with slide 'active' attribute. So I create a watch func to to this dirty job. [Here is Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/EptU2qOx2IOCoG0NSHOV?p=preview). Enjoy it: ) Night.